# Sceneform: GLB model not casting shadows

Tags: android, gltf, sceneform

I created a ViewRenderable to go underneath my GLB model, but it doesn't seem to result in any shadow being cast on the viewRenderable.

What am I doing wrong?

```kotlin
class ShadowSelectionVisualizer : SelectionVisualizer {
        private val footprintNode: Node = Node()

        fun setFootprintRenderable(viewRenderable: ViewRenderable) {
            val copyRenderable = viewRenderable.makeCopy()
            copyRenderable.verticalAlignment = ViewRenderable.VerticalAlignment.CENTER
            val rotation1: Quaternion = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 90f)
            footprintNode.renderable = copyRenderable
            footprintNode.localRotation = rotation1
        }

        override fun applySelectionVisual(node: BaseTransformableNode) {
            if (node.collisionShape is Box) {
                val box: Box = node.collisionShape as Box
                val vector3: Vector3 = box.size
                (footprintNode.renderable as ViewRenderable).sizer = ViewSizer {
                    val bound = if (vector3.x > vector3.z) vector3.x else vector3.z
                    Vector3(bound, bound, 0.0f)
                }
                footprintNode.setParent(node)
            }
        }

        override fun removeSelectionVisual(node: BaseTransformableNode?) {
            footprintNode.setParent(null)
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
myModelRenderable.isShadowCaster = true

val selectionVisualizer = ShadowSelectionVisualizer()
val transformationSystem = TransformationSystem(resources.displayMetrics, selectionVisualizer)

 ViewRenderable.builder()
            .setView(
                context, R.layout.shadow_receiver
            )
            .setRegistryId("someId.glb")
            .build()
            .thenAccept { viewRenderable: ViewRenderable ->
                viewRenderable.isShadowCaster = false
                viewRenderable.isShadowReceiver = true
                selectionVisualizer.setFootprintRenderable(viewRenderable)
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
viewRenderable.isShadowCaster = false
```

Set this to true. More information here: https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/Renderable#isShadowCaster()

Comment: I don't want viewRenderable to cast the shadow. I want it to receive shadows.